# JFileChooser .txt extension

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser, filedialog

I have developed simple notepad application in java . When I want to save file I want to add .txt extension to that file. This is working fine in file dialog

```
String filename;
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(Editor.this,"Save File",FileDialog.SAVE);
fd.show();
if (fd.getFile()!=null)
{
    filename = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile()+".txt";
    setTitle(filename);
}
```

It's working fine in the FileDialog with finename.txt

But when I take

```
String filename;
JFileChooser save = new JFilechooser();
```

Try to add extension

```
filename =save.getDirectory() + save.getFile()+".txt";
```

It's not working how can i solve this issue?

Comment: If you do not give any sample input, the output you expect and what you get instead, nobody will be able to help

Comment: Is it me or does JFileChooser not even have getDirectory() and getFile() methods?

Comment: here i am trying to open a save dialog and trying to save the file with extension of .txt how can i achieve its working fine in filechooser but not working in Jfilechooser?

Comment: @daveychu  `JFileChooser` has [`getCurrentDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getCurrentDirectory%28%29) & [`getSelectedFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile%28%29).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was just wondering why topic starter posted non-compiling code.

Comment: @daveychu The question does flip between the AWT & Swing versions of a file chooser.  Have to agree it is a little confusing though.

Answer (score 2):

In `JFileChooser` to get the file you use:

```
File currentFile= save.getCurrentFile();
```

and only then you get what you need (for example the path):

```
String fileName = file.getPath();
```

On the side note, `JFileChooser` has a nice documentation, make sure you read it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html